# Texto de fechamento "ampla demais" está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Aparentemente foi feita alguma alteração no texto que o retornou para inglês.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Valeu!

Consertado, vai pro ar no próximo build